# Options to reduce processing rate using Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.7 and Spring Kafka. I have a KafkaListener which is a continuously processing stats data from a topic and writing the data into MongoDB and Elasticsearch (using Spring Data).

My configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class StatListenerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConfig kafkaConfig;
  
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, StatsRequestDto> statsConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaConfig.statsConsumerConfigs());
    }
  
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, StatsRequestDto> kafkaStatsListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, StatsRequestDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(statsConsumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
        return factory;
    }
}

@Service
public class StatListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private StatsService statsService;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.stats}", containerFactory = "kafkaStatsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(@Payload StatsRequestDto data) {
      
        Stat stats = statsService.convertToStats(data);
        statsService.save(stats).get();   
    }
}
```

The `save` method is an async method.

The problem I am having is that when the queue is being processed, Elastisearch CPU consumption is around 250%. This leads to sporadic timeout errors across the application. I am looking into how I can optimise Elasticsearch as indexing can cause CPU spikes.

I wanted to check that if I used an async method (like above), the next message from the topic would not be processed until the previous one had completed. If that is correct, what options are there in Spring Kafka that I could use to relieve pressure of a downstream operation that might take time to complete.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 2.3, we added the `idleBetweenPolls` container property.

With earlier versions, you could simulate that by, say, sleeping in the consumer for some time after some number of records.

You just need to be sure the sleep+processing time for the records returned by a poll does not exceed `max.poll.intervsl.ms`, to avoid a rebalance.

Comment: Thanks Gary, looks like I have that property. I just wanted to check that async methods wouldn't cause a problem with the listener. Just looking at the documentation, I guess with the idle I could also get a list of consumer records and process them as a batch as opposed to one by one. I would probably need to increase the size of the poll'd records though.

Comment: Yes; batch mode would make it easier - when async processing, you really don't want to commit the offsets of the incoming batch until all the async work is complete.

Comment: Thanks Gary, top advice as always.